# Change selector from '.x-list-item' to '.x-list-item > .x-dock-vertical > .x-dock-body'

Tags: sencha-touch-2, selector

like the Title says:
I need to know how to change the selector from '.x-list-item' to '.x-list-item > .x-dock-vertical > .x-dock-body' in Sencha Touch.

Thx.
Flat

Comment: What do you mean by 'Changing the selector' ?

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/blog/whats-coming-in-sencha-touch-2-1 the sencha docs on selectectedCls confuses me. i dont know if the mean the item that is selected or the view.

Comment: "Due to these changes, the DOM structure was altered for lists, and you may need to change some CSS selectors to add appropriate styling for your lists. Typically, you need to change the selector from '.x-list-item' to '.x-list-item > .x-dock-vertical > .x-dock-body' for any padding or margins you may have added." It means that if you ever overrode the .x-list-item CSS class somewhere, now you need to override .x-list-item > .x-dock-vertical > .x-dock-body. And the selectedCls is applied on the item, not on the list.